# Roslyn Analyzer to replace type declarations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I need to implement a Roslyn Analyzer and CodeFixProvider to replace declared types in properties and parameters.
For example, I have a declaration like

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Collection { get; }
```

and I need it to be replaced with

```
public IReadOnlyList<string> Collection { get; }
```

Question: What is the best way to find such places in sources using a descendant class of DiagnosticAnalyzer?
There are many methods like:

```
RegisterSyntaxNodeAction()
RegisterSymbolAction()
RegisterSyntaxTreeAction()
```

Where would it be better to start? It would be great to find some examples also, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to implement it this way:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze | GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);

    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
        AnalyzeNode,
        SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration,
        SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration,
        SyntaxKind.Parameter);
}

private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var type = context.Node switch
    {
        PropertyDeclarationSyntax p => p.Type,
        FieldDeclarationSyntax p => p.Declaration.Type,
        ParameterSyntax p => p.Type,
        _ => null
    };

    if (type is null)
        return;

    if (!(type is GenericNameSyntax))
        return;

    if (type.GetFirstToken().ToString() == "IReadOnlyCollection")
    {
        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, type.GetLocation());
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}
```

Looks good as I can see. Please feel free to add more details if you know a better way.

Comment: Should this handle the case of a IReadOnlyCollection in another object (array, list dictionary, etc)?  I.e. arr[] IReadOnlyCollection<int>

Comment: @jmoreno This implementation works only with IReadOnlyCollection<T> in property, fields, and parameter declarations. It does not work with something like IList<IReadOnlyCollection<T>>